# Html input radio with multiple array name attribute validation failed

Tags: jquery, html, input, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I have below    radio buttons

```
<div class="col-md-12 clearfix multi-wrap">
  <div class="radio-inline"><label for="">Academics</label></div>
  <div class="radio-inline">
    <label class="radio-label" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221);">1
      <input type="radio" name="criteria_order[academics][]" value="1" required="" aria-required="true" class="text-danger">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-inline">
    <label class="radio-label" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221);">2
      <input type="radio" name="criteria_order[academics][]" value="2" required="" aria-required="true" class="text-danger">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-inline">
    <label class="radio-label" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221);">3
      <input type="radio" name="criteria_order[academics][]" value="3" required="" aria-required="true" class="text-danger">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-inline">
    <label class="radio-label" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221);">4
      <input type="radio" name="criteria_order[academics][]" value="4" required="" aria-required="true" class="text-danger">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-inline">
    <label class="radio-label" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221);">5
      <input type="radio" name="criteria_order[academics][]" value="5" required="" aria-required="true" class="text-danger">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-inline">
    <label class="radio-label" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221);">6
      <input type="radio" name="criteria_order[academics][]" value="6" required="" aria-required="true" class="text-danger">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-inline">
    <label class="radio-label" style="background: rgb(221, 221, 221);">7
      <input type="radio" name="criteria_order[academics][]" value="7" required="" aria-required="true" class="text-danger">
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

On click I am enabling checked attribute to true via JQuery like below

```
$('.radio-label').click(function(){

    $(this).closest('.multi-wrap').find('.radio-label').removeClass('active');

    $(this).closest('.multi-wrap').find('.radio-label input[type="radio"]').attr('checked',false);

    $(this).addClass('active');

    $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').attr('checked',true);
  });
```

The HTML after JQuery is like below:

```
 <input type="radio" name="criteria_order[academics][]" value="2" required="" aria-required="true" class="text-danger" checked="checked" aria-invalid="true">
```

JQuery validate is not validating. it is still showing the field is required.

**Note:** I noticed the attribute checked is appearing but when i view it it is not actually visible on page.

Comment: Can you please post you jQuery code?

Comment: edited my question. please check now

Comment: Where is your validation code

Comment: Why are you setting the input `.checked` from your JS? Doesn't that happen automatically through standard label/input element click behaviour? Having said that, if you do need to set it from JS for some reason, use `.prop()`, not `.attr()`, you want to update the current property value not the attribute.

Comment: I am hiding the radio buttons for UX purpose. if you see my jquery u will understand it. on clicking radio-label i am checking the radio via JQuery.

Comment: @nnnnnn that done the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `.change()` after `.attr()` function.